# Historical data files for NYSE/NASDAQ daily open/close price data?

Tags: stock-analysis, historical-data, stock-markets

is there a place to get free access to NYSE/NASDAQ historical daily open/close data?  Perhaps going back like 10 years?  I'm more interested in the DOW and NASDAQ 100 data for this range, not necessarily the entire market set.

I am thinking flat file/.csv.  Something I can download and run some analysis on using a wide range of tools.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Infochimps has what you are looking for: [NYSE](http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/nyse-daily-1970-2010-open-close-high-low-and-volume) and [NASDAQ](http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/nasdaq-exchange-daily-1970-2010-open-close-high-low-and-volume).

Comment: Those links are dead now (2016-03-11).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibly more flexible option is Yahoo finance here is an example for the dow..

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EDJI&a=9&b=1&c=1928&d=3&e=10&f=2012&g=d&z=66&y=0

Some of the individual stocks you can dl directly to a spreadsheet (not sure why this isn't offer for indexs but copy and paste should work).

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=ACTC.OB+Historical+Prices